# Set local variable rspec helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

I am trying to set local variable in view helper through rspec. My routine is as follow

```
def time_format(time)
    now = Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.timezone)
end
```

My spec file is as follow:

```
it 'return 12 hour format' do
      user = User.first
      assign(:current_user, user)
      expect(helper.time_format(900)).to eq('9:00 AM')
end
```

Spec is failing throwing me error undefined local variable or method 'current_user'

'current_user' resided in application_controller

Answer (score 6):

#### Problem

Your `current_user` method is not available in your rspec test. That's why you are getting the mentioned error.

#### Solution

You either can implement `current_user` method inside a test helper and then use that in your test, or you can stub `current_user` in your spec test like this:

```
let(:user) { User.new }

# RSpec version >= 3 syntax:
before { allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) { user } }
before { allow(view).to receive(:current_user) { user } }

# RSpec version <= 2 syntax:
before { controller.stub(:current_user) { user } }
before { view.stub(:current_user) { user } }
```

This should fix your problem.

Also, if you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, then I would recommend you to take a look at: [How To: Test controllers with Rails 3 and 4 (and RSpec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still stuck there. I have used your solution and it is throwing me a long stack ending with this statement "does not implement: current_user".
I have also tried 'allow_any_instance_of' and it is throwing me this error:
" NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ancestors' for #<#<Class:0x00000009911398>:0x0000000991f4c0>"

Comment: Why are you stuck? Did you try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The following was modified from the [RSpec-core 3.10 docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/configuration/custom-settings).

Create a new setting for `RSpec.configure` called `my_variable`, and give it a value, like this:

```rb
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.add_setting :my_variable
  config.my_variable = "Value of my_variable"
end
```

Access settings like class variables in `RSpec.configuration` from your test:

```rb
# spec/my_spec.rb

RSpec.describe(MyModule) do
  it "creates an instance of something" do
    my_instance = MyModule::MyClass.new(RSpec.configuration.my_variable)
  end
end
```